# Disable auto-punctuation on html input for chrome, safari etc on MacOs

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, textbox, keypress

Is there a way to disable auto-punctuate feature in html input text field and textarea?

For example after typing a word and double tapping space key immediately, a dot is automatically added in-between the 2 spaces in the textfield, this also causes the keypress javascript event to be fired just once instead of twice.

Answer (score 3):

HTML input fields don't have this behavior by default, you'd have to implement it by yourself.

If you're experiencing this on mobile (Android), it's a setting that the user can enable in the keyboard settings. It doesn't depend on the browser though.

**EDIT:**
MacOS has the same behavior as mobile keyboards. To disable it, check out [this article](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/12/19/how-to-stop-your-mac-from-inserting-a-period-when-you-double-press-the-space-bar/).

Comment: I am experiencing it on desktop webpage. Does it mean I have to tell my my users to disable it manually? I was thinking there might be an api provided by browsers to disable it.

Comment: Could it be that you've installed some tool or extension that's responsible for doing that? On which system are you, Linux, Mac or Windows, and which browsers have you tested?

Comment: It is on mac, have you tried to replicate the error using latest chrome or safari on your computer? you could just test it using the google search input.

Comment: Yeah I've just tried it, doesn't work on Linux and I haven't experienced it on Windows either. Check [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25699?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) and [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac/word-automatically-adding-a-period-after-two/577ff1b2-5169-4c31-99c1-11048e879fd8) link, it seems that it's a MacOS thing. Maybe you can try to disable it.

Comment: Okay I see, it is only on MacOs. Thanks.

Comment: It's not only on MacOs. Nowadays auto punctuation is available in most of mobile device keyboards. I couldn’t find a workaround of this yet. No matter what logic I try, it gets overridden. Will update here if I find any workaround.